# jboss5 sending email over smtp + tls

Tags: email, ssl, smtp, jboss5.x

I'm, having problems sending emails over smtp with TLS enabled on port 587 on Jboss5.1

the problem looks like this : 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I have also tried to add the CA keys in the jre keystor with the java keytool ... It looks like i'm missing something here...any hints?

I have this settings in mail-service.xml:

```
    <property name="mail.store.protocol" value="pop3"/>
    <property name="mail.transport.protocol" value="smtp"/>

    <!-- Change to the user who will receive mail  -->
    <property name="mail.user" value="********"/>

    <!-- Change to the mail server  -->
    <property name="mail.pop3.host" value="**************"/>

    <!-- Change to the SMTP gateway server -->
    <property name="mail.smtp.host" value="************"/>

    <!-- The mail server port -->
    <property name="mail.smtp.port" value="587"/>

    <property name="mail.smtp.auth" value="true"/>

    <property name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable" value="true" />

    <!-- Change to the address mail will be from  -->
    <property name="mail.from" value="**********"/>

    <!-- Enable debugging output from the javamail classes -->
    <property name="mail.debug" value="true"/>
```

and this is the debug log:

```
2013-08-08 14:24:30,031  DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4ea
2013-08-08 14:24:30,031  DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_35/jre/lib/javamail.providers (No such file or directory)
2013-08-08 14:24:30,033  DEBUG: URL vfszip:/usr/share/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/4pm_services-ear.ear/jboss-seam.jar/META-INF/javamail.providers
2013-08-08 14:24:30,034  DEBUG: Bad provider entry:
2013-08-08 14:24:30,034  DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: vfszip:/usr/share/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/4pm_services-ear.ear/jboss-seam.jar/META-INF/javamail.providers
2013-08-08 14:24:30,034  DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
2013-08-08 14:24:30,034  DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
2013-08-08 14:24:30,034  DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], org.jboss.seam.mock.MockTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,mock,org.jboss.seam.mock.MockTransport,JBoss Seam Integration Tests], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
2013-08-08 14:24:30,034  DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], mock=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,mock,org.jboss.seam.mock.MockTransport,JBoss Seam Integration Tests], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
2013-08-08 14:24:30,035  DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
2013-08-08 14:24:30,036  DEBUG: !anyLoaded
2013-08-08 14:24:30,036  DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.address.map
2013-08-08 14:24:30,036  DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_35/jre/lib/javamail.address.map (No such file or directory)
2013-08-08 14:24:30,036  DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
2013-08-08 14:24:30,036  DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
2013-08-08 14:24:30,036  DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
2013-08-08 14:24:30,036  DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "**************", port 587, isSSL false
2013-08-08 14:24:30,038  220 ************** Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 8 Aug 2013 14:24:29 +0200
2013-08-08 14:24:30,038  DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "**************", port: 587
2013-08-08 14:24:30,039  EHLO **************
2013-08-08 14:24:30,040  250-************** Hello [**************]
250-SIZE 10485760
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH GSSAPI NTLM
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250 CHUNKING
2013-08-08 14:24:30,040  DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10485760"
2013-08-08 14:24:30,040  DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
2013-08-08 14:24:30,040  DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
2013-08-08 14:24:30,040  DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
2013-08-08 14:24:30,040  DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
2013-08-08 14:24:30,040  DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "GSSAPI NTLM"
2013-08-08 14:24:30,040  DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
2013-08-08 14:24:30,040  DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
2013-08-08 14:24:30,040  DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
2013-08-08 14:24:30,040  STARTTLS
2013-08-08 14:24:30,041  220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
2013-08-08 14:24:30,041  EHLO **************
2013-08-08 14:24:30,048 ERROR
[si.arctur.fourPmServices.scheduleJobs.emailSender.MailSender] (4pm_services_QuartzScheduler_Worker-3) Error in transport email[1040]
javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX    path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to   find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1420)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1408)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.ehlo(SMTPTransport.java:847)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:384)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at   si.arctur.fourPmServices.scheduleJobs.emailSender.MailSender.actualSend(MailSender.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor$1.work(TransactionInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Work.workInTransaction(Work.java:61)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
    at si.arctur.fourPmServices.scheduleJobs.emailSender.MailSender_$$_javassist_seam_8.actualSend(MailSender_$$_javassist_seam_8.java)
    at si.arctur.fourPmServices.scheduleJobs.emailSender.MailChecker.checkQueue(MailChecker.java:41)
    at si.arctur.fourPmServices.scheduleJobs.emailSender.MailChecker.execute(MailChecker.java:22)
    at si.arctur.fourPmServices.scheduleJobs.QuartzJobBase.executeInternal(QuartzJobBase.java:94)
    at si.arctur.fourPmServices.scheduleJobs.QuartzJobBase.schedule(QuartzJobBase.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor383.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.async.AsynchronousInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
    at si.arctur.fourPmServices.scheduleJobs.emailSender.MailChecker_$$_javassist_seam_2.schedule(MailChecker_$$_javassist_seam_2.java)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor382.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:144)
    at org.jboss.seam.async.AsynchronousInvocation$1.process(AsynchronousInvocation.java:62)
    at org.jboss.seam.async.Asynchronous$ContextualAsynchronousRequest.run(Asynchronous.java:80)
    at org.jboss.seam.async.AsynchronousInvocation.execute(AsynchronousInvocation.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.async.QuartzDispatcher$QuartzJob.execute(QuartzDispatcher.java:243)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1764)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1206)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:958)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1203)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:654)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:100)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceOutputStream.write(TraceOutputStream.java:101)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1418)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:323)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:217)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1185)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:318)
    ... 80 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to enter in the keystore the certificate of the mail server, I got the certificate via

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.server.com:587 -starttls smtp
```

and I extracted the key from the response and added it in the jre keytore